# Default for Gatsby createRedirect that doesn't match condition, it should have default redirect

Tags: redirect, gatsby, netlify

I am interested in [createRedirect](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/actions/#createRedirect) actions.

I would like to utilize this to redirect user in specific country with particular language, and give english for unspecified country.

```
createRedirect({
  fromPath: `/`,
  toPath: `/id/`,
  conditions: {
    country: "id",
  },
});

createRedirect({
  fromPath: `/`,
  toPath: `/en/`,
});
```

I use [gatsby-plugin-meta-redirect](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-meta-redirect/) to make the redirect possible.

I then deploy the preview through netlify. When I tested for non `id` country using VPN, it still redirect to `/id/` instead of `/en/`.

The question is
**How to make a default redirect for non specified country?**

Answer (score 0):

Redirects like the one you are suggesting only works in Gatsby Cloud, as the docs points out:

> `createRedirect`
>
> Create a redirect from one page to another. Redirects work out of the
> box with Gatsby Cloud. Read more about [working with redirects on
> Gatsby Cloud](https://support.gatsbyjs.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500003051241-Working-with-Redirects).

To deal with [redirects in Netlify](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/) you need to create a `_redirects` (without extension) file in the `/static` folder of your project, as it needs to be published in the public folder. Because you need more complex redirection the workaround is slightly different: in this case you need to create a `netlify.toml` file at the root of your project with something like:

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/"
  to = "/id"
  status = 301
  force = false
  conditions = {Language = ["id"]}

[[redirects]]
  from = "/en"
  to = "/"
  status = 301
  force = false
```

You can read more details about the parameters and its values in the docs: https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/#syntax-for-the-netlify-configuration-file

Comment: let say that I will use the method you are suggesting, did it also answer my question? will that be redirect to `/en` for non `id` country,  @Ferran ?

Comment: Test it, and you will see, but it should. Your trials are doing exactly the same, but the order of the rules will matter, so try switching them